# How to calculate pbkdf2 SHA512 hash in C#

Tags: c#, python, hash, sha512, pbkdf2

I need a C# expert. Here is 2-line example from python:

```
from passlib.context import CryptContext
print CryptContext(['pbkdf2_sha512']).encrypt('testtest')
```

Can it be achieved with C# in some reasonable number of lines?

Comment: Use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` in C#

Comment: Rfc2898DeriveBytes uses SHA1 not SHA512

Comment: That's the only implementation of pbkdf2 baked into the .net framework. If he needs compatibility with SHA256 implementations of pbkdf2, he'll have to find a third party library to do it.